# Extracting segments of Data object in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have a 60 byte `Data` stream as follows

```
let myDataStream = Data(bytes: [24, 163, 209, 194, 255, 1, 184, 230, 37, 208, 140, 201, 6, 0, 64, 0, 7, 98, 108, 117, ...])
```

Byte #1 (index 0) represents represent the length of the first object, so in this case the first object is comprised of the first 24 objects including byte #1

I have tried numerous methods but I have been unable to figure out

1. How to extract the first 24 bytes into a new Data object
2. How to remove the first 24 bytes from `myDataStream` once #1 has been accomplished. As byte #25 will again have size of next object

The closest I have come to solving #1 is

```
let streamLength = Int(myDataStream[0])
let newStream = Data(bytes: myDataStream[0...streamLength])
```

but I get an error stating `cannot invoke initializer for Data with Data.subsequence`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can utilize a combination of the `subdata` and `removeSubRange` methods to achieve your desired results.

`subData(in:)` is an instance method on a `Data` struct.

`removeSubRange()` is also an instance method on a `Data` struct.

You can read more about these methods here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/data

**Example Method:**

```
func extract(from data: inout Data) -> Data? {
    guard data.count > 0 else {
        return nil
    }

    // Define the length of data to return
    let length = Int.init(data[0])

    // Create a range based on the length of data to return
    let range = Range(0..<length)

    // Get a new copy of data
    let subData = data.subdata(in: range)

    // Mutate data
    data.removeSubrange(range)

    // Return the new copy of data
    return subData
}
```

**Usage:**

```
// Data (27 bytes)
var data = Data(bytes: [24, 163, 209, 194, 255, 1, 184, 230, 37, 208, 140, 201, 6, 0, 64, 0, 7, 98, 108, 117, 42, 63, 78, 200, 3, 34, 36])

// First extraction
let first = extract(from: &data)
print(first!) // Prints 24 bytes
print(data) // Prints 3 bytes

// Second extraction
let second = extract(from: &data)
print(second!) // Prints 3 bytes
print(data) // Prints 0 bytes

// Third extraction
let third = extract(from: &data)
print(third ?? "No Data") // Prints "No Data"
```

**Making an Extension**

You could also wrap the `extract` method above in an extension of `Data` as follows:

```
extension Data {
    mutating func extract() -> Data? {
        guard self.count > 0 else {
            return nil
        }

        // Define the length of data to return
        let length = Int.init(self[0])

        // Create a range based on the length of data to return
        let range = Range(0..<length)

        // Get a new copy of data
        let subData = self.subdata(in: range)

        // Mutate data
        self.removeSubrange(range)

        // Return the new copy of data
        return subData
    }
}
```

Then you could you use the method like this:

```
// Data (27 bytes)
var data = Data(bytes: [24, 163, 209, 194, 255, 1, 184, 230, 37, 208, 140, 201, 6, 0, 64, 0, 7, 98, 108, 117, 42, 63, 78, 200, 3, 34, 36])

// First extraction
let first = data.extract()
print(first!) // Prints 24 bytes
print(data) // Prints 3 bytes

// Second extraction
let second = data.extract()
print(second!) // Prints 3 bytes
print(data) // Prints 0 bytes

// Third extraction
let third = data.extract()
print(third ?? "No Data") // Prints "No Data"
```

Answer (score 5):

`Data` has dedicated functions to handle `subdata`:

```
let streamLength = Int(myDataStream[0])
let newStream = myDataStream.subdata(in: 1..<streamLength + 1)
let nextStream = myDataStream.subdata(in: streamLength + 1..<myDataStream.count)
```

Answer (score -1):

You're probably looking for [`InputStream`.](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/inputstream)

```
import Foundation

let data = Data(bytes: [24, 163, 209, 194, 255, 1, 184, 230, 37, 208, 140, 201, 6, 0, 64, 0, 7, 98, 108, 117])

let dataStream = InputStream(data: data)
dataStream.open()

let numBytesPerObject = 2
var buffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: numBytesPerObject)

while dataStream.read(&buffer, maxLength: numBytesPerObject) != 0 {
    print(buffer)
}
```

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer to the question.

Comment: Hello Alexander - not sure if I understood your solution correctly but how does it help me extract the first 24 bytes and put it in a new stream? Also, how does it help remove the first 24 bytes from the original stream after I have finished processing them?

Comment: @ChicagoSky First of all, what you're dealing with is `Data`, not a "stream". This is important to distinguish, because I'm actually using a stream (an `InputStream`). In this example I show how to print every `numBytesPerObject` bytes. I set it to `2`, but you could change it to `24` for your use

Comment: Obviously printing was an example, you would change that with whatever you need the 24 bytes for